# Save figure of a plot following a conversion from notebook to Wolfram script

Tags: plotting, export, notebooks, scripting, save

I have the following Mathematica notebook on this link [notebook link](http://31.207.36.11/DB_equations.nb)

I have converted it to Wolfram script. Once done this, I am trying to save the plots as `png` image format.

Here the Wolfram script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript
(* ::Package:: *)

(* ::Subchapter:: *)
(*For cold dark matter evolution*)


DSolve[\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\ \(\[Rho][t]\)\)+3 \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\ \(a[t]\)\)/a[t] \[Rho][t]==0,\[Rho][t],t]


{{\[Rho][t]->C[1]/a[t]^3}}


(* ::Text:: *)
(*Therefore for the matter evolution we have \[Rho][t]=\[Rho]0 a[t]^-3*)


(* ::Subchapter:: *)
(*The \[Phi] field evolution will be calculated from  \[EmptySmallSquare]\[Phi]=(8\[Pi] c^-4)/(3+2\[Omega]) T*)


DSolve[\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\ \(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\ \[Phi][t]\)\)+3 \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\ \(a[t]\)\)/a[t] \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\ \(\[Phi][t]\)\)==(8 \[Pi])/(3+2\[Omega]BD) \[Rho]0 a[t]^-3,\[Phi][t],t]


(* ::Text:: *)
(*we use \[Phi][t] to calculate \!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), \(.\)]\)*)


(* ::Subchapter:: *)
(* \!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), \(.\)]\) used to calculate scale factor*)


\[Phi]Solve[t]= C2+Integrate[(C1/a[w]^3+(8 \[Pi] \[Rho]0 w)/((3+2 \[Omega]BD) a[w]^3)),{w,1,t}]


d\[Phi][t]=\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\ \(\[Phi]Solve[t]\)\)


(* ::Text:: *)
(*On the other hand, since Subscript[\[Rho], c]=(3Subscript[H, 0]^2 Subscript[\[Phi], 0])/(8 \[Pi]) and  \[Rho][t]=\[Rho]0 a[t]^-3=Subscript[\[Rho], c] Subscript[\[CapitalOmega], m] a[t]^-3 for  \!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), \(.\)]\) we will get following final form*)


d\[Phi][t]=d\[Phi][t]/.{\[Rho]0-> (3H0^2 \[Phi]0)/(8 \[Pi]) \[CapitalOmega]m}


(* ::Subchapter:: *)
(*The Hubble constant Subscript[H, 0], or equivalently the Hubble time Subscript[T, 0]=1/Subscript[H, 0]*)


H0=71.0


Th=((1/H0 ) (3.09 10^19)/(3.15 10^7))10^-9


(* ::Title:: *)
(*Parameters of BD model:*)


\[CapitalOmega]m=0.3


\[CapitalOmega]c=0.0


\[Omega]BD = 0.75


\[Phi]0=1.0


C1=1.5


a0=0.001


(* ::Subchapter:: *)
(*Solve BD model *)


BDSolve=NDSolve[{\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\ \(a[t]\)\)==H0 Sqrt[\[Phi]0 \[CapitalOmega]m 1/\[Phi][t] a[t]^-1+1/H0^2 ( \[Omega]BD/6  (\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\ \(\[Phi][t]\)\)/\[Phi][t])^2- ( \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\ \(\[Phi][t]\)\)\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\ \(a[t]\)\))/(a[t]\[Phi][t] ))a[t]^2-\[CapitalOmega]c],\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\ \(\[Phi][t]\)\)==d\[Phi][t],\[Phi][0]==\[Phi]0,a[0]==a0},{a[t],\[Phi][t]},{t,0,40}]


a[t]=a[t]/.BDSolve[[2]][[1]]


Plot[a[t],{t,0,3},PlotRange->All]


H[t]=\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\ \(a[t]\)\)/a[t]


Plot[H[t],{t,0,3}]
```

I tried for the plot command above :

```
plotat=Plot[a[t],{t,0,3},PlotRange->All]
Export["Scale_factor_BD.png", plotat]
```

But I don't get the expected plot and this generates actually a void plot.

What is the woraround to save a valid plot under `png` or `jpeg` format image ?

EDIT 1: @Rohit Namjoshi. Thanks ! it works, I get the following figure :

[image: plot]

Now, how to add easily labels on both axis and legend on this plot ?

Comment: Remove this `a[t] = a[t] /. BDSolve[[2]][[1]]` then clear all symbols or exit the kernel then `aSol = a[t] /. BDSolve[[2]][[1]]`, `Plot[aSol, {t, 0, 40}]`. Make sure your code works in a notebook before attempting to run it with `wolframscript`.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi . Thanks for your fix. Why doesn't it work with the original line `a[t] = a[t] /. BDSolve[[2]][[1]]` : where is the error ? I am curious .. 

Moreover, as I say in my **EDIT**, how to add easily labels on both axes and a legend ?

Comment: It is rarely a good idea to give values to symbols that are part of the differential equation. Especially in a notebook, after `a[t] = a[t] /. <solution>` the original `NDSolve` will no longer work. `BDSolve` is a list of  `InterpolatingFunction` that already depend on `t` so the replacement is essential defining a[t]=a[t][t].

Comment: Check the documentation for `Plot` there are a lot of examples of labeling and legending.